# Threads vs Processors for Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, cpu, 64-bit, vba, parallel-processing

I'm writing a VBA module that uses a lot of computational power. To speed things up, I'm using all available processors on my machine. Excel gives me an option though to use a different number of threads. Is there a difference between (for example) specifying 8 processors versus selecting 8 threads? Would selecting 7 threads limit the machine to using 7 processors?

Thank you

Comment: What are the names of the options you use for both of these?

Comment: @dsolimano http://ccm.net/faq/11398-excel-select-the-default-number-of-processors-to-be-used-for-calculations

Comment: @wizlog, ok, so there's only one option.  I think the linked question should probably answer you now.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I'm specifically referring to how the options within Excel work.

Comment: This entirely depends on the processors.  If each of those processors were single threaded core processors, then indicating you wanted to use 7 of those processors, would indeed mean your script would be limited to 7 threads.  I am not aware of any hardware that supports 7 processors, nor are there a great deal of single threaded core processors on the market.